# Assign permissions to Routes in UI

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-permission

I have implemented the spatie laravel permissions module in my application and it is working perfectly. Currently I have all my routes protected with permissions using the Middleware of the module, but I have to define the permissions in the web.php file. Is there a way to assign these permissions to the routes by storing them in the DB? I have thought about doing it by creating a controller that assigns the permissions and then checking them with a middleware, but is there any other more optimal way to do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO...   Pls post the code of what you are doing in web.php in your question

Comment: Yes, you could do that. But, you are overengineering the application. Use Route::group() to assign permissions to sections of your routes. The permissions itself are already stored in the database. 

Otherwise, if you really wish to do it... You can make a new middleware (or enhance the existing onces) that detects the current route and retrieves the permission from the database corresponding to your route. But I'd advise against it for readability and performance of your application.